# Braces don't work when there is a single element

Tags: shell, brace-expansion

I am able to scp files based on their extensions as,

```
 scp sk@localhost:/home/sk/*.{txt,text} .
```

But when I try to scp a single extension type, it fails,

```
 scp sk@localhost:/home/sk/*.{txt} .
```

I was able to solve this error by removing the flower brackets in case#2,

I am just curious why does using flower brackets fail in case, there is only file extension type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you're using bash, [the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) says:

> A correctly-formed brace expansion must contain unquoted opening and
>   closing braces, and at least one unquoted comma or a valid sequence
>   expression. Any incorrectly formed brace expansion is left unchanged.

Thus, `{foo}` is not a correctly-formed brace expansion:

```
$ bash -c 'echo {foo} {foo,bar}'
{foo} foo bar
```

Comment: And how to achieve it? how to write an expression of brace shell expansion with only one element?

Answer (score 3):

What you're calling "flower brackets" are normally called "braces", and the functionality you're using is called "brace expansion".  The bash man page documents it this way:

```
   Brace Expansion
       Brace expansion is a mechanism by which arbitrary strings may be generated.
       This mechanism is similar to pathname expansion, but the  filenames  gener-
       ated  need  not  exist.   Patterns to be brace expanded take the form of an
       optional preamble, followed by either a series of  comma-separated  strings
       or  a sequence expression between a pair of braces, followed by an optional
       postscript.  The preamble is prefixed to each string contained  within  the
       braces,  and  the  postscript  is  then  appended to each resulting string,
       expanding left to right.
```

When you only put a single extension in the braces, it's not a brace expansion, because it doesn't match either of the formats listed (either comma separated strings or a sequence expression between a pair of braces).  So, it's not expanded and instead left unchanged.

Comment: And how to achieve it? how to write an expression of brace shell expansion with only one element?